# View model not updating UI

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following classes

**PostsViewModel.java**

```
......
//Boolean observable to toggle the visibility of progress bar
public static final ObservableBoolean postsLoading = new ObservableBoolean(false);

private void getPosts() {
    postsLoading.set(true);
    getPostRepository().getPosts(new PostDataSource.LoadPostCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPostsLoaded(List<Post> posts) {
            boolean isEmpty = posts == null || posts.isEmpty();

            //setting the post loading false here
            postsLoading.set(false);

            Log.d(TAG, "onPostsLoaded: posts loading set to false");
            if (!isEmpty) {
                mPostObservable.clear();
                mPostObservable.addAll(posts);
            }
            errorViewShowing.set(isEmpty);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataNotAvailable(String message) {
            postsLoading.set(false);
            errorViewShowing.set(true);
            errorString.set(message);
        }
    });
}
......
```

**PostActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PostList binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    PostsViewModel mPostsViewModel = new PostsViewModel();
    binding.setPostViewModel(mPostsViewModel);
    mPostsViewModel.getPosts(); //calling get posts here
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data class="PostList">

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="postViewModel"
        type="com.example.vuclip.mvvm_repository.posts.PostsViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".posts.PostsActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="@{ postViewModel.postsLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I want to toggle the visibility of the progress bar based on the value of `postsLoading` ObservableBoolean variable in my `PostsViewModel`. I checked using debugger and confirmed that my code does setting the value of the `postsLoading` variable to false but still the progress bar remains visible.

Looks like the changes in the Observable fields are not notified to the layout file for some reason. What am I going wrong here?

I have enabled dataBinding in my gradle file.

Comment: Do I have to call some method to notify the changes, I know we have to call `notifyChange()` in case if Bindable fields but is it required for BaseObservable classes also?

Comment: did you try to find `setVisibility` in the generated code and setup a breakpoint there?

Comment: not yet, not sure how to do that actually. Let me try that

Comment: no, no need when using `Observable[<PrimitiveType>]`s - see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/ObservableBoolean.java#66

Comment: I can't find the visibility toggle generated code. :(

Comment: check `ActivityMainBinding.java` and `ActivityMainBindingImpl.java`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169053/discussion-between-ezio-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink can you please comment why the code is running after removing the static field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my Observable field was static. I dont really know why this is happening but as soon as I removed the static field everything it starts working.